# IPv6 validation

Tags: java, regex, parsing, validation, ipv6

I used `IPAddressUtil.isIPv6LiteralAddress (ipAddress)` method to validate IPv6, but this method fails for ipv6-address/prefix-length format (format is mentioned in [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) section 2.3) of IPV6.

Could anyone know any validators which validate " ipv6-address/prefix-length "  format?

**Legal representations of IPV6**

1. ABCD:EF01:2345:6789:ABCD:EF01:2345:6789
2. 2001:DB8:0:0:8:800:200C:417A
3. FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101
4. 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
5. 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
6. 2001:DB8::8:800:200C:417A
7. FF01::101
8. ::1
9. ::
10. 0:0:0:0:0:0:13.1.68.3
11. 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:129.144.52.38
12. ::13.1.68.3
13. FFFF:129.144.52.38
14. 2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60
15. 2001:0DB8::CD30:0:0:0:0/60
16. 2001:0DB8:0:CD30::/60

### **NOT legal representations of IPV6**

1. 2001:0DB8:0:CD3/60
2. 2001:0DB8::CD30/60
3. 2001:0DB8::CD3/60

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are trying to match?

Comment: Sure, please see below ip address, 2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/60

Comment: That format is for address *prefixes,* not addresses.

Comment: @Tony, were you able to find a solution? I am also looking to parse IPv6 prefix addresses.

Comment: 2 and 3 in the second group are perfectly legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```
try {
    if (subjectString.matches(
        "(?ix)\\A(?:                                                  # Anchor address\n" +
        " (?:  # Mixed\n" +
        "  (?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){6}                                # Non-compressed\n" +
        " |(?=(?:[A-F0-9]{0,4}:){2,6}                           # Compressed with 2 to 6 colons\n" +
        "     (?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}                     #    and 4 bytes\n" +
        "     \\z)                                               #    and anchored\n" +
        "  (([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){1,5}|:)((:[0-9A-F]{1,4}){1,5}:|:)  #    and at most 1 double colon\n" +
        " |::(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){5}                              # Compressed with 7 colons and 5 numbers\n" +
        " )\n" +
        " (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}  # 255.255.255.\n" +
        " (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])           # 255\n" +
        "|     # Standard\n" +
        " (?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[A-F0-9]{1,4}                    # Standard\n" +
        "|     # Compressed\n" +
        " (?=(?:[A-F0-9]{0,4}:){0,7}[A-F0-9]{0,4}               # Compressed with at most 7 colons\n" +
        "    \\z)                                                #    and anchored\n" +
        " (([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){1,7}|:)((:[0-9A-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)    #    and at most 1 double colon\n" +
        "|(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}:|:(:[A-F0-9]{1,4}){7}           # Compressed with 8 colons\n" +
        ")/[A-F0-9]{0,4}\\z                                                    # Anchor address")) 
        {
        // String matched entirely
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

I purchased a very helpful program called RegexMagic nearly a year ago for some complicated regular expressions I planned on using.

This was suppose to be Java, so it should compile, I assume the /60 can be between the ranges of 0000 and FFFF you can modify that last part.

/[A-F0-9]{0,4} is what I added to the regular expression to match your example.

Comment: the Regex above *might* work... but this is so ginormous, I can't imagine someone (including the original author) having a clue how to dissect it a year later.  Instead of chaining so many `|`, I would break it into a bunch of "else if" statements, which at a minimum facilitates much easier debugging

Comment: For IPv4, it is 0-32. For IPv6, it is 0-128. 32 or 128 would be a single address, 31 or 127 would be two addresses, 30 or 126 would be four addresses, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Guava library, specifically using the `com.google.common.net.InetAddresses` class, calling [`isInetAddress()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html#isInetAddress(java.lang.String)).

---

**isInetAddress**

`public static boolean isInetAddress(String ipString)`

Returns true if the supplied string is a valid IP string literal, false otherwise.

**Parameters**: `ipString` - String to evaluated as an IP string literal

**Returns**: `true` if the argument is a valid IP string literal

Comment: It does not work for IPv6 prefixes. Only works for IPv6 addresses. @broc.seib

Answer (score 4):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports parsing both IPv4 and IPv6 CIDR subnets (ie address/prefix format) in a polymorphic manner. Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

The following method is example code for validating:

```
static void parse(String str) {
    IPAddressString addrString = new IPAddressString(str);
    try {
         IPAddress addr = addrString.toAddress();
         IPAddress hostAddr = addrString.toHostAddress();
         Integer prefix = addr.getNetworkPrefixLength();
         if(prefix == null) {
             System.out.println(addr + " has no prefix length"); 
         } else {
             System.out.println(addr + " has host address " + hostAddr + " and prefix length " + prefix);
         }
    } catch(AddressStringException e) {
        System.out.println(addrString + " is invalid: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Using the examples provided in the question, the output of the above method is:

```
abcd:ef01:2345:6789:abcd:ef01:2345:6789 has no prefix length
2001:db8::8:800:200c:417a has no prefix length
ff01::101 has no prefix length
::1 has no prefix length
:: has no prefix length
2001:db8::8:800:200c:417a has no prefix length
ff01::101 has no prefix length
::1 has no prefix length
:: has no prefix length
::d01:4403 has no prefix length
::ffff:8190:3426 has no prefix length
::d01:4403 has no prefix length
FFFF:129.144.52.38 is invalid: FFFF:129.144.52.38 IP Address error: address has too few segments
2001:db8:0:cd30::/60 has host address 2001:db8:0:cd30:: and prefix length 60
2001:db8:0:cd30::/60 has host address 2001:db8:0:cd30:: and prefix length 60
2001:db8:0:cd30::/60 has host address 2001:db8:0:cd30:: and prefix length 60
2001:0DB8:0:CD3/60 is invalid: 2001:0DB8:0:CD3/60 IP Address error: address has too few segments
2001:db8::cd30/60 has host address 2001:db8::cd30 and prefix length 60
2001:db8::cd3/60 has host address 2001:db8::cd3 and prefix length 60
```

As you can see, the question was incorrect about FFFF:129.144.52.38 being valid and about 2001:db8::cd30/60 and 2001:db8::cd3/60 being invalid.  The first one would be valid if it were ::FFFF:129.144.52.38

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to split it into two part, prefix address and prefix len.

> **1. validate prefix address use the some regex to validate IPv6 address**
>   **2. validate the prefix len that must be an integer**
>   **3. prefix address can only have ':' s less than the result of`prefix len divided by 16`**
>   **4. other logic must be considered as well, leave TODOs here, sorry:(**

```
  private int validateIPv6AddrWithPrefix(String address) {
        int occurCount = 0;
        for(char c : address) {
            if(c=='/'){
                occurCount++;
            }
        }
        if(occurCount != 1){
         //not good, to much / character
            return -1;
        }
        /* 2nd element should be an integer */
        String[] ss = pool.getAddress().split("/");
        Integer prefixLen = null;
        try{
            prefixLen = Integer.valueOf(ss[1]);
                    // TODO validate the prefix range(1, 128)

        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            /* not a Integer */
            return -1;
        }
        /* 1st element should be ipv6 address */
        if(!IPaddrUtilities.isIPv6Address(ss[0])) {
            return -1;
        }
        /* validate ':' character logic */
        occurCount = 0;
        for(char c : ss[0].toCharArray()){
            if(c==':') {
                occurCount++;
            }
        }
        if(occurCount >= prefixLen/16) {
            // to much ':' character
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete Java solution for IPV6 validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a section 2.3 does not describe an address representation, but a representation of address **prefix** (even the "full-length" prefix is not the same as an address).

> An IPv6 address prefix is
>      represented by the notation:
>         ipv6-address/prefix-length
>      where
>         ipv6-address    is an IPv6 address in any of the notations listed
>                         in Section 2.2.

That means you may safely disregard this format if you need to validate addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried below regex in java and it worked for IPV4 and IPV6

```
public class Utilities {
private static Pattern VALID_IPV4_PATTERN = null;
private static Pattern VALID_IPV6_PATTERN = null;
private static final String ipv4Pattern = "(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
private static final String ipv6Pattern = "([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9a-f]){1,4}";

static {
try {
  VALID_IPV4_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ipv4Pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  VALID_IPV6_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ipv6Pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
  //logger.severe("Unable to compile pattern", e);
 }
}

 /**
 * Determine if the given string is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.  This method
 * uses pattern matching to see if the given string could be a valid IP address.
 *
 * @param ipAddress A string that is to be examined to verify whether or not
 * it could be a valid IP address.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the string is a value that is a valid IP address,
 *  <code>false</code> otherwise.
 */
 public static boolean isIpAddress(String ipAddress) {

Matcher m1 = Utilities.VALID_IPV4_PATTERN.matcher(ipAddress);
if (m1.matches()) {
  return true;
}
Matcher m2 = Utilities.VALID_IPV6_PATTERN.matcher(ipAddress);
return m2.matches();
  }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to even try to handle the :: versions and the ones that end with an IPv4 address.

Comment: A slight modification to the IPV6 pattern:

    Pattern VALID_IPV6_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-f]{1,4}:{1,2}){4,7}([0-9a-f]){1,4}", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);