# Open source IPv6 Java validation

Tags: java, validation, ipv6

Now that all sun.* proprietary APIs may be removed in the future, does anyone know any open source Java implementation of IPv6 validation?

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963199/ipv6-validation), it'd be also nice to have native ipv6-address/prefix-length format support to.

Comment: Presumably, the APIs won't be removed until the Java platform provides equivalent functionality.  Have you tried using `Inet6Address.getByAddress` or `InetAddress.getByName` as a validator?

Comment: Maybe [this lib from Jan Van Besien](http://janvanbesien.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/java-library-for-ipv6.html) ?

Comment: Caution: Inet6Address.getByName can lead to DNS queries if you feed e.g. a broken address like "::1::" into it. This can take a couple of seconds on a single call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will validate both IPv6 and IPv4 and also supports prefix-length (and validation of such).  I am the project manager of that library.

Use

```
try {
    IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString("::1");
    IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
} catch(IPAddressStringException e) {
    //e.getMessage has validation error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html) library (there is isInetAddress() method)